# Box2d simulation slowing down on some devces

Tags: android, performance, box2d, game-physics

I have made a physics based game using Processing and Eclipse that is using Box2d. My game is working fine on PC and my Samsung S3 but the physics simulation is too slow on LG G2 (although G2 is running at 60fps while S3 at 45-50fps). I am stepping Box2d as:

```
box2d.step((float) (1.0 / frameRate * 1.4), (int) frameRate / 8, (int) frameRate / 8);
```

Kindly tell me what can I do to run the simulation smoothly on every device?

Comment: Have you profiled the code to see where it's getting slowed down?

Comment: overall simulation is slow. The code is same for all the devices so I think the problem is with the step function. There may be an efficient way to step the box2d world.

Comment: profile it and compare the values passed into step on different devices, at best we can only make wild guesses with so little info. At least post more code, ie it's unclear what framerate is and how it is calculated.

Comment: I will have to put my whole game here for you to check the problem and I think I cannot put nearly 7000 lines of code here. As I said the game is running at 60fps on LG G2 and at 45fps on Samsung S3 but the simulation is slow on LG G2 as compared to Samsung S3. As for your question, the variable "frameRate" used in above code returns the current FrameRate of the game.

Comment: Is frameRate a constant value? If not, it should be.

Comment: no frameRate is not a constant value. I am using Processing 2.x and frameRate is a variable that returns current frameRate the game is currently running at. It changes at each call to draw() function